# Buttons on bottom layer don't work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have 4 buttons on stage, 2 on top layer and 2 on the bottom layer. the top layer buttons overlaps the bottom buttons. The top buttons hide themselves when They are clicked (which works good) as I can see bottom buttons appear. The problem is buttons on the bottom layers are in active, even though there listeners have been setup just as for the top layer buttons?
I tried `btn.enabled=true;` `btn.mouseChildren =false;` and `btn.buttonMode=true`for bottom buttons, even over rid the listeners twice but no help. Is it a Flash IDE problem ? I am new to Flash and ActionScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the common invisible overlapping issue. Have you set the `.alpha = 0;` for the top buttons when they are clicked ?
if yes, then that's the problem. Change that to `.visible=false;`.

try that!

Comment: COOL. That WORKED. Whats the difference ? I thought both alpha and visible handles the visibility of the object?

Comment: Actually both are different things. `.visible` determines whether or not the object should be rendered by the player while `.alpha` sets the opacity of an object. So in your case the `.alpha=0` meant that the top buttons are not visible but they are still there above the bottom buttons which blocks your interactivity with the bottom buttons.

Comment: Ah now it all make sense! Totally understood Thanks for the explanation Yawar =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Trace every action of your button,
then find is the click listener is active or not..